# Get a record's current partition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, partitioning

In SQL Server 2008 R2, how would I determine what partition a record currently lives in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you can identify a row or set of rows already in the table, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT $PARTITION.[PartitionFunctionName](PartitioningColumn)
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE <clause to identify rows>;
```

If you have just a value, and it's not necessarily in the table yet, you can tell what partition it would be in given the current state using [`$PARTITION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) independently:

```
SELECT $PARTITION.[PartitionFunctionName](SomeConstant);
```

(This is also useful shorthand if you are identifying the row(s) in the table using the same column.)

Comment: Excellent. I looked into the $partition function but read a question on this site that left some doubt as to whether a record automatically moves to a different partition when its data changes. Is $partition accurate 100% of the time (no delays in moving to new partition, etc.)?

Comment: Well I can't speak for what happens if you use the function *while* a partition is being switched, or while data is being moved or updated, but if the data's at rest I don't see how there would ever be an issue.

Comment: Yes, it will move the data. It is recommended however that the partition column be immutable: <http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/19d16022-e02e-4b85-95b6-707a490af90e>

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone, Very good. The link had an issue but I was able to sort it out: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/19d16022-e02e-4b85-95b6-707a490af90e

Comment: @GaTechThomas: `$PARTITION` is a virtual column. It doesn't store any data, it simply evaluates the partitioning function over the given input value. If data moves (during a partition split or partition split, not during a switch) then you cannot access the data to start with during the move, so there's no point asking what the return is. Partition *switch* does not move any data. In other words, the result is always 100% accurate.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, Am I correct in thinking that you meant to say something other than "during a partition split or partition split"? What is the term used to say that data moved to a new partition because the data that it is partitioned upon was changed?

Comment: I mean 'split' or 'merge', as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186307.aspx

Comment: @GaTechThomas ideally, you're not changing the actual partitioning key. This shouldn't be a common scenario at all, can you describe your use case?

Comment: An update of a partition column value that causes the row to move across partition boundaries is two distinct operations: a delete from the old partition and an insert into the new partition. Never can a row have a partitioning column value for partition X and reside in partition Y.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, We don't change the key value. I was just curious to know what would happen in the case that it did occur.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the $PARTITION function to achieve this. The link below should help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188071.aspx