# Find the partition where data lives in MySQL

Tags: mysql, partitioning, mysql-5.6

Is there a way to select the partition name where a specified record actually lives in? The idea is something like:

```
SELECT <PARTITION_NAME> FROM mytable WHERE <where_condition>
```

I found a similar question for SQL Server: [Get a record's current partition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/22638/24218), but not for MySQL.

Comment: Hi, you can't select the partition name in one SELECT statement. Ue the system table "information_schema.partitions", filter on TABLE_SCHEMA and TABLE_NAME. Then play with PARTITION_DESCRIPTION to find your data. Give us your table structure and your partition method if you need some help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the way you propose works well but is quite slow in my case, especially considering dynamically created queries. I would need to select the partition attribute for each query, then find the corresponding partition in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.partitions. I need the partition information to speed up a SELECT * FROM <table> PARTITION <partition>, so quickly (sub)selecting the partition would be really helpful.